# SQL query, 3 tables

Tags: sql

I'm in trouble and hopefully there's someone willing to help...
I know the following query is not working, mostly because I'm not an expert for this stuff, but it should give you idea what my goal is. Here's my own interpretation:

```
SELECT ID, user_login, user_email FROM wp_users (
SELECT SUM( no_votes )
FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = wp_users.ID 
) + (
SELECT SUM( comment_karma )
FROM wp_comments WHERE user_id = wp_users.ID )
```

It should output the list of all users, collect basic info from "wp_users" table and sum number of votes from two other tables ("wp_posts" and "wp_comments") where wp_users.ID match is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With subqueries in the Select clause:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  user_login, 
  user_email,
  (SELECT SUM( no_votes ) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = wp_users.ID) 
  + (SELECT SUM( comment_karma ) FROM wp_comments WHERE user_id = wp_users.ID) 
  as votes_and_karma
FROM wp_users
```

Or with subqueriesin the FROM clause:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  user_login, 
  user_email,
  wp_posts_group.sum_no_votes
  + wp_comments_group.sum_comment_karma
  as votes_and_karma
FROM wp_users
  left outer join 
    (SELECT 
       post_author,
       SUM(no_votes) as sum_no_votes
     FROM wp_posts 
     GROUP BY post_author) wp_posts_group
    ON wp_posts_group.post_author = wp_users.ID
  left outer join 
    (SELECT 
       user_id,
       SUM(comment_karma) as sum_comment_karma
     FROM wp_comments 
     GROUP BY user_id) wp_comments_group
    ON wp_comments_group.user_id = wp_users.ID
```

Comment: I've never seen a select in the columns part of a select before.  Am I correct to assume that these inner selects have to return exactly 1 column and 1 row?

Comment: Stefan, this does seem to working - partially. I have tested your query but, beside "ID", "user_login" and "user_email" there are 2 extra columns in result: "sum_no_votes" and "sum_comment_karma". These two should be summed. Anyway, thanks a lot for your efforts, I could never come out with something like that nor I thought it might be so complex.

Comment: I didn't recognize that you sum the two values again. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be sure without testing it against your data, but something like this should get you started:

```
SELECT 
    wp_users.ID, 
    wp_users.user_login, 
    wp_users.user_email,
    SUM(wp_posts.no_votes),
    SUM(wp_comments.comment_karma)
FROM 
    wp_users 
    left join wp_posts on post_author = wp_users.ID 
    left join wp_comments on user_id = wp_users.ID 
group by
    wp_users.ID,
    wp_users.user_login,
    wp_users.user_email
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The joins are multiplying the rows of all joined tables and SUM will return wrong values.

Comment: @Stefan, true but in Rob's defense, I was writing the exact same query (albeit a lot slower) and falling in the same trap.

Comment: @Lieven: I was about to write the same as alternative solution in my answer :-) then I fixed it. SQL is so tricky.

Comment: Rob, this doesn't seem to be working, SQL throws an error reading "Column 'ID' in field list is ambiguous"

Answer (score 0):

I'll accept Stefan's Answer as final because he pointed me to the right direction. After messing around with it I came out with the following, which by the way, fits exactly to my needs:

```
SELECT ID, user_login, user_email, (
(
SELECT SUM( no_votes )
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_author = wp_users.ID
) + (
SELECT SUM( comment_karma )
FROM wp_comments
WHERE user_id = wp_users.ID )
) AS total
FROM wp_users
ORDER BY total DESC
```